# Created app in React Native latest version doesn't works

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native. I am using these versions.

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.58.4
```

After creating app as

```
react-native init cameraapp
```

It created a folder cameraapp. Now when I am running in cameraapp folder, after starting emulator.

```
react-native run-android
```

I am getting error this error.. map of undefined.

This is stacktrace below

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
 DELTA  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 60.8% (403/517)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2019:07:19:16 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at resolveDependencies (D:\Training\react native\cameraapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:388:18)
    at D:\Training\react native\cameraapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:261:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\Training\react native\cameraapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
    at _next (D:\Training\react native\cameraapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:107:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

[image]
[image]

Note: I have not edited this app yet. Just Started from command line after creating.

Comment: Try adding this in android/build.gradle file inside allprojects -> repositories `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`

Comment: Still getinng the same error [Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10814624/shubham-bisht)

Comment: You don't have anything in your code?

Comment: At some point in your code you’re calling `.map`. Search for all instances of `.map`. Something you’re calling `.map` on is undefined.

Comment: See the stacktrace in post, I have not used. Actually just created this app. Nothing edited. [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508175/andrew).
This is coming from internal node_module I guess

Comment: Just have the default app provided by react-native @[Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10814624/shubham-bisht)

Comment: @Andrew He is right. I also did create a new React native app with the new version with only default code provided by the react native and I also got similar error

Comment: @Vikash.777 please ask this question on Github and also on React Native groups in Facebook. :)

Comment: [Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10814624/shubham-bisht), Can you edit this post, so that others can understand this problem in much better way? May be atleast it's title as per this problem.

Comment: @Vikash.777 Do you get the error if you try `react-native init cameraapp --version react-native@0.58.3`?

Comment: No error, I get while creating app

Comment: @Vikash.777 I'd recommend you to ask the question again

Comment: @Vikash.777 ask the question again and post it on github too. And also on React Native groups in Facebook

Comment: [Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10814624/shubham-bisht), My project is now working fine. I did nothing to solve. Now I am creating new apps, They are working fine